# VScode unittest configuration

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I generally use this command to run my python (3.6) unittests from my project root directory

`python -m unittest discover -v -s . -p "test_*.py"`

However, I am not able to set it up using vscode. My configuration is

```
  "python.testing.unittestArgs": ["-v", "-s", ".", "-p", "test_*.py"],
  "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true
```

And I get the message

```
No tests discovered, please check the configuration settings for the tests.
```

How do I correct my vscode settings to run the unittests.

Comment: You use different path to tests in command line and in VS Code config. Is it correct?

Comment: Oops, sorry I was trying various paths in the vscode settings. Now corrected.

Comment: Look at what is displayed in the `Python Test Log` output. You can find it in `View` -> `Output` -> then choose type of output on the right side of console.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing "`.`" in the configuration to the direct parent folder location of the test file.

like this:

```
"python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./A/a",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
```

Specify the exact location of the test file and it will be found.

Reference:[This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface).

Comment: I am at the project level and the tests are distributed across various modules, so I cannot specify a parent folder other than `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
 "python.testing.unittestArgs": ["-v", "-s", ".", "-p", "test*.py"],
```

worked.